# JavaScript Regular Expression to replace text in given URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a web tool to promote products with my affiliate link. 
I need to modify a URL as follows.

My URL may be in this format

```
https://www.example.com/productid
http://www.example.com/productid&
https://www.example.com/productid
https://example.com/productid
http://example.com/productid
```

Now I need to write a regular expression to convert those URLS into this format

```
https://abc.example.com/abc/productid
```

Can someone help with the regular expression to do this?

Comment: Why not simply replace `.com/` by `.com/abc/` and `http:` by `https:` using `.replace()`? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Regex:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\/productid(?:.*)
```

Replace with: `https://abc.example.com/abc/productid`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vCWQ8U/1/)

```js
var input = `https://www.example.com/productid
http://www.example.com/productid&
https://www.example.com/productid
https://example.com/productid
http://example.com/productid
httpL//www.stackoverflow.com`

var replaceWith = "https://abc.example.com/abc/productid";
output = input.replace(/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\/productid(?:.*)/g, replaceWith);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You should be clear with your requirements. Add all conditions and examples to the question. How about: https://regex101.com/r/vCWQ8U/5?